# new process is no longer capturing output

Tags: c#, winforms, process, minecraft

I had this working at one time and I compared it to my old code but I don't see where I have made any changes to this recently. I'm at a loss at this point.

I am trying to run a Minecraft server. I want the output to be displayed in my richtextbox. Like I said, this was working fine.

Anyhow, here is the code:

```
   public void RunMinecraftsServer()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_serverProc != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The server is already running.");
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox_JarFile.Text) ||
                !File.Exists(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, textBox_JarFile.Text)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Jar file does not exists. Please select a jar file for the server to run and start again.");
                return;
            }

            var serverparms = string.Format("-Xms{0}M -Xmx{1}M -jar {2} nogui -nojline",
                numericUpDown_Xms.Text, numericUpDown_Xmx.Text, _settings.CurrentSettings.JarFileName);
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(_settings.CurrentSettings.JavaPathAndExe, serverparms)
            {
                WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
            };
          startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
          startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
              startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            // create process
            _serverProc = new Process();
            _serverProc.StartInfo = startInfo;
            _serverProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            // bind events
            _serverProc.ErrorDataReceived += ServerProcErrorDataReceived;
            _serverProc.OutputDataReceived += ServerProcOutputDataReceived;
            _serverProc.Exited += ServerProcExited;
            // start the process and monitor
            _serverProc.Start();
            _serverProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            textBox_SubmitCommand.KeyDown += TextBoxSubmitCommandKeyDown;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            Logging.LogException(ex);
        }
    }
```

And I'm capturing it here, or at least should be:

```
    private void ServerProcOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox_Console.InvokeRequired)
        {
            richTextBox_Console.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => ServerProcErrorDataReceived(sender, e)));
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox_Console.Text += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
            richTextBox_Console.SelectionStart = richTextBox_Console.Text.Length;
            richTextBox_Console.ScrollToCaret();
            ParseServerInput(e.Data);
            ParseServerInput(e.Data);
        }
    }
```

I put a breakpoint on this method and it never reaches it.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT#3**

I resolved the coding issue that was brought to my attention.

I changed:

```
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

to:

```
          startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
          startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
              startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

Still no output though :(

Comment: You forgot to set RedirectStandardOutput to *true*.  The code in the *else* clause in your ServerProcOutputDataReceived() method will never run.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry for the mix up, I am getting anxious to get this resolved. I have added the 3 lines above with not resolve.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `_serverProc.BeginErrorReadLine();` so you'll read from stderr, but you forgot to call `_serverProc.BeginOutputReadLine();`, so you'll never read anything from stdout and you will never reach `ServerProcOutputDataReceived`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding code to wait for the process to end before you leave the RunMinecraftsServer method. Something like this:

```
public void RunMinecraftsServer()
{
    try
    {
        ...

         var dtEndTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes( 1 );
         while ( !serverProc.HasExited && ( DateTime.Now < dtEndTime ) )
         {
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 500 ) );
              serverProc.Refresh();
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Another thing you can try is to make sure that the MincraftServer is writing a carriage return and line feed to the output before it ends. Believe it or not, I've seen cases were the monitoring application will not get the child's output if the child does not write a CR/LF to the output.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The serverProc stays running as long as the server is running. I'd never leave that loop until I sent an 'stop' command to the server. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently calling:

```
// start the process and monitor
_serverProc.Start();
_serverProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
textBox_SubmitCommand.KeyDown += TextBoxSubmitCommandKeyDown;
```

and not calling:

```
_serverProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

which means ServerProcOutputDataReceived will never be called. Add BeginOutputReadLine() by BeginErrorReadLine() and it should then work!